# Rewriting to a Directx 3D11 Buffer

Tags: c#, directx, slimdx

I am only able to write one time to the vertex buffer without re declaring the entire class.

The original write

```
SlimDX.Direct3D11.Buffer vertexBuffer;
vertexBuffer = new SlimDX.Direct3D11.Buffer(DeviceManager.Instance.device,
            vertices,
            SizeOfVertexBufferInBytes,
            ResourceUsage.Default,
            BindFlags.VertexBuffer,
            CpuAccessFlags.None,
            ResourceOptionFlags.None,
            0);
```

The Code that is being used to rewrite the buffer. It is currently not moving, just trying to rewrite.

```
public void Move(Vector3 deltaVec)
{
    this.vertexBuffer.Dispose();
    vertexBuffer = new SlimDX.Direct3D11.Buffer(DeviceManager.Instance.device,
            vertices,
            SizeOfVertexBufferInBytes,
            ResourceUsage.Default,
            BindFlags.VertexBuffer,
            CpuAccessFlags.None,
            ResourceOptionFlags.None,
            0);
    render();
}
```

How would I be able to rewrite this buffer to change the position of the vertices. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that happens to get the same problem as me, I believe that I have found a solution. in the Move function, I never set the position back to 0.(This leads to it indexing out?). any way here is the fixed code.

```
public void Move(Vector3 deltaVec)
    {
        this.vertices.Close();
        vertices = new DataStream(SizeOfVertexBufferInBytes, true, true);
        foreach (Vector3 vec in this.verticiesList)
        {
            vertices.Write(vec + deltaVec);
        }

        vertices.Position = 0;

        // create the vertex layout and buffer
        var elements = new[] { 
            new InputElement("POSITION", 0, Format.R32G32B32_Float, 0)
        };
        layout = new InputLayout(DeviceManager.Instance.device, inputSignature, elements);


        vertexBuffer = new SlimDX.Direct3D11.Buffer(DeviceManager.Instance.device,
            vertices,
            SizeOfVertexBufferInBytes,
            ResourceUsage.Default,
            BindFlags.VertexBuffer,
            CpuAccessFlags.None,
            ResourceOptionFlags.None,
            0);
        render();
    }
```

Good Luck!